# Como ler uma planilha do Excel 2013 e gravar em um banco de dados PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados

Estou com problemas em gravar informações no banco de dados.

Essas informações eu extraio de um arquivo do Excel.

Por exemplo, tenho 3 campos e não sei como pegar a 1ª célula e gravar no banco, depois pegar a 2ª e gravar e por fim pegar a 3ª e gravar.

Lembrando que são várias informações que cada coluna possui.

Meu código está assim:

```
public void readingSheet(String path) {

    try {  

       File file = new File(path);  

       String name = file.toString();  

       int pos = name.lastIndexOf('.');  

       String ext = name.substring(pos + 1);  

       FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);  

       Workbook obj = null;  

       if (ext.equals("xlsx")) {

           try {  
               //Metodo aceita o path do arquivo  
               obj = new XSSFWorkbook(fileIn);  
           } 

           catch (IOException ex) {  
               throw new RuntimeException(ex);  
           }  
       } 

       else if (ext.equals("xls")) {  

           try {  
               //Metodo nao aceita string do path do arquivo  
               obj = new HSSFWorkbook(fileIn);  
           } 
           catch (IOException e) {  
               throw new RuntimeException(e);  
           }  
       }  

       else {  
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arquivo recebido não é uma extensão do Excel");  
       }  

       int o = 0;  

       Sheet worksheet = obj.getSheet("Plan1");  

       Row row;  

       Cell cell;  

       for(int i = 1; i<= worksheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){  

           row = worksheet.getRow(i);  

           String linha = "";  

           for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {  
               cell = row.getCell(j);  

               if(cell.getCellType()==1)   {
                   linha += " | " + cell.getStringCellValue();
               }

               else {  
                   double aux = 0;  
                   int aux2 = 0;  
                   aux = cell.getNumericCellValue();  
                   aux2 = (int) aux;  
                   linha += " | " + aux2;
              }  
          }  
           System.out.println("");
           System.out.println("Linha: " + linha);  
           System.out.println("");
       }    

   } 

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
      e.printStackTrace();
   }  

}
```

Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Poderia colocar exemplos de valores das colunas? Dependendo do caso se possível, é mais simples converter a planilha em csv e importar esse arquivo direto pelo banco.

Comment: Claro, username "Fernando" - fullname "Fernando Santos" - password "teste"

Answer (score 1):

Aconselho a usar a biblioteca [jxl](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) para manipular planilhas do excel. Só não testei com o excel 2013.
Aqui vai um exemplo de manipulação

O código de exemplo é esse

```
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.WorkbookSettings;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public void readingSheet(String caminho_arquivo_xls) {
    //objeto relativo ao arquivo excel
    Workbook workbook = null;

    try {
        //Carrega planilha
        WorkbookSettings config = new WorkbookSettings();
        config.setEncoding("Cp1252");//configura acentuação
        workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(caminho_arquivo_xls),config);//recupera arquivo desejado
        //recupera pagina/planilha/aba do arquivo
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
        //recupera numero de linhas
        int linhas = sheet.getRows();
        //percorre todas as linhas da planilha
        for (int row = 0; row < linhas; row++) {
            //cria meu objeto que recebe as linhas
            MeuObjeto objeto = new MeuObjeto();
            //verifica se coluna 0 (A) e linha row não é vazia
            if(!sheet.getCell(0,row).getContents().isEmpty()){
                //recupera informação da coluna A linha row.
                objeto.setDadoA(sheet.getCell(0, row).getContents().toString());
            }
            if(!sheet.getCell(1,row).getContents().isEmpty()){
                //recupera informação da coluna B linha row.
                objeto.setDadoB(sheet.getCell(1, row).getContents().toString());
            }
            //chama meu objeto que faz o serviço de salvar no banco de dados
            bancodados.salvarDado(objeto);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        print_erro(e);
    } catch (BiffException e) {
        print_erro(e);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        print_erro(e);
    } catch(Exception e){
        print_erro(e);
    } finally {
        //fechar
        if (workbook != null)
            workbook.close();
    }
}
```